# Escaping \x from strings

Tags: c#, regex

Well, I got this little method:

```
static string escapeString(string str) {
    string s = str.Replace(@"\r", "\r").Replace(@"\n", "\n").Replace(@"\t", "\t");
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\x(..)");
    var matches = regex.Matches(s);
    foreach (Match match in matches) {
        s = s.Replace(match.Value, ((char)Convert.ToByte(match.Value.Replace(@"\x", ""), 16)).ToString());
    }

    return s;
}
```

It replaces "\x65" from String, which I've got in args[0].

But my Problem is: "\\x65" will be replaced too, so I get "\e". I'd tried to figure out a regex which would check if there are more then one backslashs, but I had no luck.

Can sombody gimme a hint?

Comment: Are you reinventing [Regex.Unescape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx)?

Comment: Why shouldn't `\\x65` become `\e`?

Comment: @bzlm: because the first \ escapes the second \

Comment: Hell Yeah! That was simple! Thx a lot! :)

Comment: Using the word "gimme" in a question is highly inadvisable.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to hack regexes together with things like "\s|\w\x(..)" to remove the case of \x65.  Obviously that will be brittle since there is no guarantee that your sequence \x65 always has a space or character in front of it. It could be the beginning of the file.  Also, your regex will match \xTT, which obviously isn't unicode.  Consider replacing the '.' with a character class like "\x([0-9a-f]{2})".

If this was a school project, I would do something like the following.  You can replace all combinations of "\" into another unlikely sequence, like "*@!!@!!@*", run the regex and replacements, and then replace all of the unlikely sequence back to "\".  For example:

```
String s = inputString.Replace(@"\\", @"_@!!@!!@_");
// do all of the regex, replacements, etc here
String output = s.Replace(@"_@!!@!!@_", @"\");
```

However, you shouldn't do this in production code because if your input stream ever has the magic sequence then you will get extra backslashes.

It's obvious that you are writing come kind of interpolator.  I feel obligated to recommend looking into something more robust like lexers that use regexes to form Finite State Machines.  Wiki has some great articles on this topic, and I'm a big fan of ANTLR.  It may be overengineering now, but if you keep running into these special cases consider solving your problem in a more general way.

Start reading here for the theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look-behind:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<!([^\]|^)\\)\\x(..)");
```

This asserts that the previous character is *not* a solo backslash, but *without capturing* the previous character (look-arounds do not capture).

Comment: This would not match `\\\x65`, but probably should.

Comment: @hvd I considered that, but hoped no one would notice :) I think I've fixed it.

Comment: Now it matches the `\x` in `\\x65` at the start of a string (since it isn't preceded by `[^\]\\ `), and it also matches `\\\\x65`. A backslash is escaped if it is preceded by an odd number of backslashes, and it is unescaped if it is preceded by an even number of backslashes. A regex just isn't the right tool for that job :)

Comment: @hvd Well I've fixed the start-of input, and I don't really care about a gazillion backslashes - that seems unlikely input, but who knows.